# Как скрыть папку .git в FileZilla?

Tags: git, github

Я не хочу копировать папку .git на удаленный сервер.
Поэтому в левом окне FileZilla она не нужна эта папка.
И получается несоответствие количества файлов и папок в левом и правом окне FileZilla

У меня windows 10, скрытые папки и файлы не отображаются, но папка git в FileZilla появляется! Как ее оттуда убрать?

Пробовал ставить галочку тут http://shot.qip.ru/00UK3W-256TNYcVa/
где Temporarary and Backup Files, не помогло.

Comment: `source control directories` похоже на тот фильтр, который вам нужен.

Comment: а где его найти?

Comment: Так я на вашей картинке прочитал, сделал предположение, дальше уж вы сами.